# Need help with simple jquery fadein/out transition

Tags: jquery, css, fadein, fadeout

Using jquery, I am trying to get a background image to fade into a different one when you mouse over it, and fade out when you take your mouse off. I have tried countless solutions over the last few hours, and can't seem to find one that applies. Below is my css

```
.thumbnail span {
    background: url('images/portfolio.png') no-repeat;
    width: 298px;
    height: 160px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-left:-2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.thumbnail span .rollover {
    background: url('images/portfolio_vignette.png') no-repeat;

}
```

and here is my JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">         
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".rollover").css({'opacity':'0'});

    $('.thumbnail span').hover(
        function() {
            $(this).find('.rollover').stop().fadeTo(500, 1);
        },
        function() {
            $(this).find('.rollover').stop().fadeTo(500, 0);
        }
    )

});     
</script>
```

Cheers guys!

Comment: Java is to JavaScript what car is to carpet. This is JavaScript, not Java.

Comment: So, you put JavaScript under Java to catch oil leaks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to put a `div` wrapper around your two images and attach the hover event to that.  If you don't, your hover will continuously trigger as the image disappears/appears.

Here, I simply fade the last element out when hovering, and in when un-hovering.  Of course, you could be more specific and act on `img` tags only, or on specific ID's.  The generic way is more useful as you never have to write the code again for another pair of images.

HTML:

```
<div class="hoverfade">
    <img src="http://my/image1.jpg">
    <img src="http://my/image2.jpg">
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".hoverfade").hover(function() {
    $(this).children().last().fadeOut(1000);
}, function() {
    $(this).children().last().fadeIn(500);
})
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/wQkWR/

Example using divs with background images: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/wQkWR/1/

Answer (score 0):

Put your 2 images exactly in the same position, then with javascript make the top image to fadeout. That will make the effect you want

Comment: You can use image tag (img) instead of background css. in the case that you want to use background css, use 2 divs overlayed

Answer (score 0):

You can access the thumbnail class to perform fade in or out.

$(.thumbnail).fadeIn('slow');

or

$(.thumbnail).fadeIn(700); // miliseconds

to fadeout do the reverse

$(.thumbnail).fadeOut('fast');

or

$(.thumbnail).fadeOut(300); // miliseconds

Answer (score 0):

Simplifying Jeff B's code..

Use jQuery's fadeToggle to avoid separate functions for the fade out and in.

http://jsfiddle.net/danielredwood/wQkWR/2/